# Is there a way in python to create a class that inherits from another class/object passed by an object?

Tags: python, class, object

I want to create a class that inherits another class and instantiates it with the object from the prev. class to have a new object from the new class ( old class attrs. and methods with new attrs. and methods).

example:

```
class A():
    attrs...

    methods...
  
class B(A):  
    def __init__(self, a_obj):
    ...

    A_attrs + B_attrs...
    
    A_methods + B_methods...

a = A()
# assign some values to 'a'
b = B(a)
# a and b should have the same params and behaviors
```

Is there a way to implement such an alternative class and use the new object?

Comment: Code filled with `...` doesn't make for a good [mre].

Comment: Have you tried `deepcopy`?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell what exactly you are trying to achieve, but having the exact things you want to forward to `a`, it is easy to achieve.

No need to use metaclasses, but depending on the behavior you want,  the special `__getattribute__` and `__setattr__` methods might help.

Take in mind that as far as *methods* are concerned, the *inheritance* mechanism will already do that: any methods called in an instance of `B` will be forwarded to the method defined in `A`, unless there is an overriding implementation of it in `B`: in this case the overriding method have to explicitly run the method in `A` by using a `super()` call, or skip it altoghether: it is up to the implementation.

Method overriding is independent of instances. If you want them to "see" a particular instance of `A` passed at `B` object instantiation, it is just the *attributes* in that instance that matter.

Now, if you want instances of `B` to proxy over to the attributes a particular instance of `A`, the special methods I mentioned can do the same bridge. We can implement those in a way that if any attribute access is attempted in attribute that existis in the `a` instance, that one is used instead.  Also, the special behavior can be implemented in a mixin class, so you are free to implement your business logic in `B`, and deffer all special attribute handling mechanisms to the mixin instead.

```
_SENTINEL = object()
        
class ProxyAttrMixins:
    def __init__(self):
        # Do nothing: just prevent the proxied class` __init__ from being run
        pass
    
    def _inner_get(self, attrname):
        bound_getattr = super().__getattribute__
        try:
            proxied = bound_getattr("proxied")
        except AttributeError:
            # No associated object to proxy to!
            # just pass an try to retrieve the attribute from `self`
            pass
        else: # no AttributeError: there is a proxied object        
            associated_attr = getattr(proxied, attrname, _SENTINEL)
            if associated_attr is not _SENTINEL:
                # if object is a callable: it is a method. A mehtod in the derived class should
                # be called if it exists, and just otherwise in the proxied object:
                if callable(associated_attr):
                    try:
                        own_method = bound_getattr(attrname)
                    except AttributeError: 
                        pass
                    else:
                        return "own", own_method
                return "proxy", associated_attr
        # if there is no proxied object, or if the proxied does not have the desired attribute,
        # return the regular instance attribute:
        return "own", bound_getattr(attrname)
        
        
    def __getattribute__(self, attrname):
        bound_getattr = super().__getattribute__
        whose, attr = bound_getattr("_inner_get")(attrname)
        return attr
    
    def __setattr__(self, attrname, value):
        bound_getattr = super().__getattribute__
        try:
            whose, attr = bound_getattr("_inner_get")(attrname)
        except AttributeError:
            whose = "own"
        if whose !=  "own":
            proxied = bound_getattr("proxied")
            return setattr(proxied, attrname, value)
        super().__setattr__(attrname, value)
        
class A:
    def __init__(self, c: int):
        self.c = c
    
class B(ProxyAttrMixins, A):
    def __init__(self, a: A):
        self.proxied = a
        super().__init__()  # this ensure B can still have colaborative inheritance. 
                            # The Mixin's __init__ prevents A __init__ from being run and
                            # report on the missing `c` argument
```

And this code allows this kind of scenario:

```
In [18]: b = B(a:=A(5))

In [19]: b.c
Out[19]: 5

In [20]: b.c = 10

In [21]: a.c
Out[21]: 10
```